# DotNetNuke List Export as csv

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

We are using Forms and list module in DNN 9 portal. We are having List with URL column. We are able to view the URL value in portal. But, when we export list as csv and If URL value is internal URL(like Portal page URL or file URL), then we get some integer instead of URL, in exported csv. Is there a way to get proper URL in csv file? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The integer is probably the TabId.  So you might be able to crest a SQL script that does an inner join with the tabs table.

If other URLs are mixed with integers, possibly create a function to be called if you get an integer.  Depending on the size of the list, it might take time, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is the TabId. As Joe said, depending on the number of cases it might be some work. If it is only a handful, it could be easier to manually replace the handful of integers by the Url itself.

In addition to Joe's answer:

To get the Url, you could use the following SQL script:

```
SELECT
   'https://' + pa.HTTPAlias + tu.[Url] AS [Url]
FROM
   {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}Tabs t
   INNER JOIN {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}TabUrls tu ON tu.TabId = t.TabID
   INNER JOIN {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}Portals p ON p.PortalID = t.PortalID
   INNER JOIN {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}PortalAlias pa ON pa.PortalID = p.PortalID
WHERE
   t.IsDeleted = 0
   AND t.DisableLink = 0
   AND tu.HttpStatus = 200
   AND pa.IsPrimary = 1
   AND t.TabID = [THE INTEGER GOES HERE]
```

Run this script in the DNN SQL Console, if you use SSMS you have to change {databaseOwner} and {objectQualifier} by the approbriate values that you find in the web.config file. Add a dot (".") after the {databaseOwner} value, eg. "dbo."

If you are not using https change the string to 'http://'.

Comment: Thanks for adding the hard details, Michael!